# Find position of Button/UIElement on screen relative to grid Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, uielement

I can't find a way to get the position in (x,y) co-ordinates of an on-screen control like a button relative to the grid that it is inside. Is there a way to do this that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var transform = button.TransformToVisual(grid);        
Point absolutePosition = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

From [How to get the position of an element in a StackPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510667/how-to-get-the-position-of-an-element-in-a-stackpanel).

Comment: I am always getting 0,0  in absolutePosition. What I am doing wrong?,