# Get left top coordinates

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to stop a tap event from propagating in a XNA / Silverlight game

Here 
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27029/how-to-stop-a-tap-event-from-propagating-in-a-xna-silverlight-game
I found solution how I should to do it.

To get `width` and `height` I use `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` property.

But how can I get left top coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.left(v=vs.95).aspx) and [Top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.top(v=vs.95).aspx) properties to get the position of the control.

Comment: In WP7 button doesn't have `Left` and `Top` property

Comment: Did not notice in your intial post :) take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206294/find-position-of-button-uielement-on-screen-relative-to-grid-windows-phone

Comment: It was in tag (windows-phone 7). Thanks a lot, it seems to work fine;)